# Handle recorded accelerometer data

Tags: swift, core-motion

I am solving problem to collect accelerometer of Apple Watch, using `CMSensorRecorder`. I got an error that

> CMSensorRecorder().accelerometerData(from: to:) sometimes returns nil

. I also checked `CMSensorRecorder.isAccelerometerRecordingAvailable() == true and CMSensorRecorder.authorizationStatus() == .authorized.` It seems `function CMSensorRecorder().recordAccelerometer(forDuration:)` not works.

Comment: Did you read the document of dis method? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmsensorrecorder/1615937-accelerometerdata

Comment: It said "*The difference in time between the fromDate and toDate must be 12 hours or less*" and "*If there were gaps in the recording, no data entries are returned for those gaps*"

Comment: I found the reason that we can not access data when charging.

Comment: @PhátTàiNguyễn comment is very important! I made this mistake several time accidently!